# Javascript move div to tag end body </body>

Tags: javascript

How to move div to before tag end body `</body>`. I'm using openx, I cannot change div content, because the content owned by others. I just put code javascript from openx in order to get banner I put the code after tag `<body>` before anyting tag in content.
And my problem is, when I put javascript from openx to generate banner I get two div parallel, which the banner in `<div id="div1">` and `<div id="div2">` there are in below tag `<body>`, I want to `<div id="div1">` after tag start body `<body>` above anyting tag in content. And `<div id="div2">` in before tag end body `</body>` after anyting tag.

This is I get html from openx, as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1"><img src="blablabla" /></div>
        <div id="div2"><img src="blablabla" /></div>
        Here is content other div id or div class,
        I not define example insert after div id footer
        Because this is content owned by others.
        This is justexample content.
    </body>
</html>
```

and I want to transform to as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1"><img src="blablabla" /></div>
        Here is content other div id or div class,
        I not define, example insert after div id footer
        Because this is content owned by others.
        This is justexample content.
        <div id="div2"><img src="blablabla" /></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Because I want to put banner one above content and banner two to below content. I don't want to use CSS `position: fixed`.

So, possible to move tag div to before tag end body?
If possible, please help me code javascript to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Plain simple javascript:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.getElementById('div2'));
```

To move the node you just use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) method.

And the demo http://jsfiddle.net/6GsbB/

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, I get error in console log Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8 with code in above

Comment: It doesn't work for you because `document.getElementById('div2')` returns `null`. Make sure you pass correct id and you *actually* have it in your HTML.

Comment: Hwhwhhw, Ahhh I accustomed to using jquery so always use the above. Now problem has been fixed with your code. Thanks man.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can do this way, but you need [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

```
a = $("#div2").clone();
$("#div2").remove();
$("body").append(a);
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/zc8Ze/

---

Plain JavaScript method.

```
var a = document.getElementById("div2");
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/zc8Ze/1/

---

From the comments, this can be made in a better efficient way, given by [dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq):

```
document.body.appendChild(document.getElementById('div2'));
```

Comment: There is no need to clone, you can just move the element, which saves memory, like this: `$('body').append($('#div2'))`

Comment: The OP didn't ask for jQuery... I would hope you weren't going suggest he include, download, evaluate a 80kb library just to `appendChild`?

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, Is there without jquery, Because it will generated to other websites, which the website owned by other, so how if the website not found jquery. Thanks.

Comment: @LorenRamly Okay, will give the JavaScript version too.

Comment: @rgthree Updated the answer. Please check and remove the downvote, if you did so. :)

Comment: Hi @PraveenKumar , I get error in console log 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property parentNode of null' on line 'element.parentNode.removeChild(element);'

Comment: @LorenRamly Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chromium browser, linux version.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sure, I'll remove it now ;)  Also, you don't need to create two references and call `removeChild`. I prefer @dfsq's answer, personally.

Comment: @rgthree Am not that good in JavaScript, so thanks, will learn from this. The reason I am not changing is, it will become a direct copy. Let me answer Loren's question.

Comment: @LorenRamly I am using Google Chrome 24. It works fine. Can you check in other browsers?

Comment: It doesn't work for you because document.getElementById('div2') returns null. Make sure you pass correct id and you actually have it in your HTML.

Comment: Okay, got it. @LorenRamly, those two lines are not needed. Remove the lines with `element`.

Comment: @dfsq I got it. Updated it too! :) Thanks... :)

Comment: Anyway, you code is correct, I will give you +1. Plus jQuery version.